# How can I populate an array with numbers, starting at one number, and ending at a different number?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, numbers, counter, populate

This is my first question. Please let me know if I have broken any rules or conventions.

I want to populate an array with numbers that are supposed to represent ages. I want this array to begin at a specific number, and end at a different number. I want each number to be a separate item in the array, represented as a number, not a string.

This is what I have:

```
const agesArr = populateAgesArr();

const maxAge = 100;
const minAge = 21;


function pupulateAgesArr () {
  let ageCount = minAge;
  for (i=0; i<maxAge, i++) {
    return ageCount++;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome!
Lets start with a typo: in `for (i=0; i<maxAge, i++)` you need `;` and not `,`: `for (i=0; i<maxAge; i++)`.

Comment: You are calling the function before it knows the max/min ages.

Comment: I'll just write a working code - and see if you understand...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I'd use the `push` method of `Array`...

Look into this code:

```js
var minAge=21;
var maxAge=100;
var agesArr=[];

function populate(arr, min, max) {
  for(var i=min; i<=max; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
}

populate(agesArr, minAge, maxAge)

console.log(agesArr);
```

If you don't want to pass the variables, then you don't really need a function - you can just do this:

```js
var minAge=21;
var maxAge=100;
var agesArr=[];

for(var i=minAge; i<=maxAge; i++) {
  agesArr.push(i);
}

console.log(agesArr);
```